# compare data in two files and replace if not matching

Tags: bash, shell

I'm using a shell script to `echo >`  data to `$outputfile` and always have an old file containing previous data `$oldouptdata`. What I need to do is as follows:

```
echo "datahereto" > $ouptputfile 
read  $oldouptdata
diff  $ouptputfile  $olouptdata
if there is a difference   then execute function  (myfunction)    then   replace $oldoutputdata  data with $outputfile data
```

This my scenario. 
Any help with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This little bash script should do the trick

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "yourstuff" > outputfile

diff outputfile oldfile

if [ $? == 1 ]; then

    # they're different!

    # call your function
    yourfunction

    # subst old with new one
    cp -f outputfile oldfile

else

    # they're the same

fi;
```

Answer (score 0):

without further information, i'd say you can just replace the previous file.  if `oldfile` is the same as `newfile`, the replacement will be a noop, if they're different, you'll get into the desired state as well.

if, for whatever reason, you need to replace `oldfile` only if it actually differs from `newfile`, use something like

```
if ! cmp -s oldfile newfile; then
  mv newfile oldfile
fi
```